# Jarque -Bera test interpretation

Tags: wiki

i have run the Jarque -Bera test and have obtained the following results,

JB=11.62 and 
p=1.

i am not able to interpret them. please help

Answer (score 0):

If your JB calculated is bigger than JB critical(you find it in a table but you have to know the level of significance) than you reject H0 else, you accept H0. You also have to take into consideration the p value. Usually if JBcalculated we accept H0(the residuals are normally distributed). Hope that this is helpful for you